# Did the wicked son see the Exodus?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

I know this is a little out of season but I am learning the Hagadah with the Malbim commentary. We are told in the Hagadah that the wise son will ask his question in the future, meaning he didn't see the miracle.  And the wicked son asks in the present, meaning he DID see it. "But now - in the generation that experienced the Exodus and witnessed the Revelation at Sinai. He asks not to fill the gaps in his knowledge, but to mock and criticize." However, we are also told if he were there, the wicked son would not have been redeemed. But if he saw the sea split then logically he WAS redeemed.

Comment: Despite you being winter woman, pesach being in the spring, and it currently being summer, Torah is never out of season!

Comment: The sons being discussed were all born after the Exodus (such as nowadays). The reference is that the wicked son does not want to continue to follow Hashem and remember the Pesach. That is why the answer is *had he been alive then*

Answer (score -2):

No. The Haggadah specifically says he would not have been saved by HaShem. And 80% of the Jews died in Misrayim because they didn’t believe in Mosheh and his message

Comment: Point 1 is spot on, @Kapin. Many of us are familiar with the midrash you cite as point 2 but a source would be really useful

Comment: I don't really understand how this is expected to help the OP.

Comment: @Kapin about as ok as usual i think